# How to get particular element with a className?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using `target.getElementsByClassName('numerical'))` to get the list of elements with classname of `numerical` . I want to further filter only `th` from the list. How can i do that?

```
0: th.ant-table-cell.numerical
1: th.ant-table-cell.numerical
2: td.ant-table-cell.numerical
3: td.ant-table-cell.numerical
```

Comment: Have you looked at `.querySelector()`?

Comment: I tried `target.querySelectorAll('.th.numerical'))` but that didnt work

Comment: That is because th is not a class. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71467417/295783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
target.querySelectorAll('th.numerical')
```

I also suggest you read up on [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

`target.querySelectorAll('th.numerical'))`

This will give you all `th` elements with className of 'numerical'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from element you get with `getElementsByClassName` and filter them like this

```
Array.from(target.getElementsByClassName('numerical'))
    .filter((tag) => {
        return tag.tagName === "TH");
    });
```

Here I use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function to convert the result of `getElementsByClassName` to Array as it is an instance of `HTMLCollection` which is not iterable.

Comment: But why would you want to do that when you can get the nodeList using `target.querySelectorAll('th.numerical')` and array from that nodeList using spread: `[...target.querySelectorAll('th.numerical')]` in case you need to map or do other array stuff

Comment: As `querySelectorAll` is started to be more popular in replacement of popular jquery selector. It's abvious to all  mention that the result of `HTMLCollection` can be converted to an Array  an based on that their can be filtered.

Comment: What I mean is, UNLESS you need a live HTMLCollection, the nodeList returned from querySelectorAll is simpler to specify and it already filters. If you need an array of the nodeList, you can simply spread it into an array